# Deleting object from one to many relationship in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, sdk

I currently have a problem deleting an object in a to many relationship.

My app have the following relationship:

Product <<- Cart

When the user pushes a "add to cart" button in my viewcontroller, the following code is setting the relations between the product object and the cart

```
    + (Cart *)addProductToCartWithProduct:(Product *)product inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {

    Cart *cart = nil;

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Cart"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *carts = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if (!carts || ([carts count] > 1)) {
        // handle error
    } else if (![carts count]) {
        cart = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Cart" inManagedObjectContext:context];


    } else { // they already have a cart started
        cart = [carts lastObject];
    }
    /*Get Object ID to safely pass NSMangedObject between threads (A background worker thread and the main thread). */
      NSManagedObjectID *retID = [product objectID];
    [cart addProductsObject:(Product *)[context objectWithID:retID]];

//Inverse relationship
    [(Product *) [context objectWithID:retID] setInCart:cart];


     return cart;
}
```

This then returns a cart object, which I pass to my cart viewcontroller, and fetch the products in that relationship like so:

```
             // Fetch request for "Product":
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Product"];

// Fetch only products for the cart:
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"inCart = %@", self.cart];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate]; 


NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"navn" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:_theManagedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
```

When I then try to delete an object from the relationship like so:

```
-(void)RemoveFromCart:(UIButton *)sender {

     NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];

    Product *prod = (Product *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:ip];



       prod.inCart = nil;
       [_cart removeProductsObject:prod];


    NSLog(@"Cart %@ %@", _cart.products, prod);


    [self saveCurrentContext:_theManagedObjectContext];




    [self loadCart]; 
    [_orderTable reloadData];


}
```

The product is removed visually (gone from the tableview/screen) because inCart is set to nil, but not technically... when I log the cart object, the product object is still in the relationship, so it seems like the `[_cart removeProductsObject:prod];` is not working.

And it also doesn't work the other way around, when I try to add the same product to the cart, I just have deleted (from the cart), for some reason the inverse relationship "inCart" is not set, after I have set it to "nil", when the product object is removed.

Why is this happening? and how do I fix it? :).

EDIT:

Pictures showcasing inverse relationships in Core data model editor:

[image]

[image]

Pass Cart to other viewcontroller:

```
[[[DataManager sharedInstance] backgroundManagedObjectContext] performBlock:^{


    UITabBarController *tabBarController = self.tabBarController; 

    for (UINavigationController *navController in  tabBarController.viewControllers) {


        for (UIViewController *vc in navController.viewControllers) {
            if ([vc isMemberOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"CartViewController")]){ 
               CartViewController *cartVC = (CartViewController *) vc;
                cartVC.cart = [Cart addProductToCartWithProduct:prod inManagedObjectContext:         [[DataManager sharedInstance] backgroundManagedObjectContext]];

                [[DataManager sharedInstance] saveBackgroundContext];
                [[DataManager sharedInstance] saveMasterContext];

                NSLog(@" %@", cartVC.cart); 
            }
        }

    }



}];
```

Save Context

```
-(void)saveCurrentContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context  {

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"NOT SAVED");
    }
    [[DataManager sharedInstance] saveBackgroundContext];
    [[DataManager sharedInstance] saveMasterContext];



}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `inCart` and `products` are properly defined as "inverse relationships" in the Core Data model editor? It should be sufficient to set (or delete) one side of the relationship and not both as you do in your code.

Comment: I am very sure that they are defined correct in my Core data model editor... I have added some screenshots (Under EDIT above), with the inverse relationship in the editor, does it seem correct? :)

Comment: The relationships look OK to me. So why do you always set the relationships in both directions?

Comment: Okay thank you. Hmm, interesting question... I think it just have become a habit and I have thought that it was some kind of "best practice" to do it that way. But even though I delete the code that set the inverse relationship, it still don't work. I don't have a clue why it isn't working.. ? :) Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that the `saveCurrentContext` operation does not fail? - Apart from that, I currently don't have an idea what might cause your problem.

Comment: I don't get any errors and it seems like it is saving (a part of my code is decrementing a quantity count of the current product and that seems to get saved). I have posted the code, where I pass the cart object to my Cart(viewcontroller) and my SaveCurrentContext method.. Thank you :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so I found a work around for this very weird problem. 
Since the autogenerated accessor methods didn't work for some reason, I had to think of another way to delete the object from the relationship.

```
          for (Product *prod in _cart.products) {

//To Very reliable to check for item by name attribute, but It works :) 
              if ([prod.name isEqualToString:product.name]) {

                        product = prod; 

       NSMutableSet *set = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:_cart.products];
       [set removeObject:prod];
       _cart.products = set;


              }


            }
```

Comment: I am having the same problem with swift + NSMutableOrderedSet. Have you managed to make this work by any chance?